# InvalidOperationException: Timeout - recursive DB access

Tags: asp.net, sql, recursion, timeout

currently I have a serious problem with one of my web applications which runs into a Timeout Exception around half a dozen times a day.

Error: "The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached".

After a lot of googling I found out that the problem has something to do with unclosed connections. So I checked all functions that access the database in any way until I stumbled upon this one:

```
    Private Sub getOrgas(ByVal orgID As String)
        Dim Id = orgID
        orgColl.Add(Id)
        While (Not IsNothing(Id))
            Dim conn = Database.DbWrapper.GetConnection(1, Integration.Mandanten.DatabaseType.AddonSQL)
            Dim paras As New HashSet(Of System.Data.Common.DbParameter)
            Dim orgatmp As String
            paras.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Id", orgID))
            Dim dr = Database.DbWrapper.GetDataReaderFromStoredProcedure("stp_Orgas_Get", paras, conn)
            While dr.Read
                If Not valueInColl(CStr(dr(0))) Then
                    orgatmp = dr(0).ToString
                    orgColl.Add(orgatmp)
                    getOrgas(orgatmp)
                End If
            End While
            dr.Close()
            conn.Close()
            Id = Nothing
        End While
    End Sub
```

As you can see this function executes a stored procedure and runs the results through a while loop where it calls the function again if a specific condition -valueInColl-. Now in that way it is possible that there are 20 or more open connections. It has nothing to do with the timeout-value which is set via the GetDataReaderFromStoredProcedure to 600 which actually should be enough. To be sure I doubled the value and will roll it out this evening. I'll see whether that helped within the next day then.
I believe the problem is that there are too many open connections at the same time, because of the recursive function, but I have no clue how to solve this.

I couldn't find anything as to how to edit the max connections. I'm not even entirely sure where have to set it. Is it the IIS, the DB itself or is it a programming-parameter (VB.net/ASP.NET).
Would be nice if you guys could help me out here.

[EDIT]
Ok, somebody had the idea to reuse the connection variable, but this won't work as the datareader is still running. As long as it is not closed I can't reuse the connection in any way and I can't close the datareader, because I might lose data if I do so. The while-loop for dr.read hasn't ended, yet ..
On the other hand I deleted the (pretty much useless) outer while and used an If-clause in exchange:

```
Private Sub getOrgas(ByVal orgID As String, ByVal con As DbConnection)
    Dim Id = orgID
    Dim conn As DbConnection
    Dim tmpOrga As String
    orgColl.Add(Id)
    If Not IsNothing(Id) Then
        If IsNothing(con) Then
            conn = Database.DbWrapper.GetConnection(1, Integration.Mandanten.DatabaseType.AddonSQL)
        Else
            conn = con
        End If
        Dim paras As New HashSet(Of System.Data.Common.DbParameter)
        paras.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Id", orgID))
        Dim dr = Database.DbWrapper.GetDataReaderFromStoredProcedure("stp_Orgas_Get", paras, conn)
        While dr.Read
            If Not valueInColl(CStr(dr(0))) Then
                tmpOrga = dr(0).ToString
                orgColl.Add(tmpOrga)
                getOrgas(tmpOrga, conn)
            End If
        End While
        dr.close()
        conn.Close()
        Id = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you cannot refactor things so that each recursion uses the same db connection?

I am not a VB coder but I would tackle it as follows

1. Change `getOrgas()` to take a connection parameter defaulting to 'nothing'.
2. Change the `Dim conn` line to `if IsNothing(connParameter) conn = GetConnection() else conn := connParameter;`
3. Change your recursion line to `getOrgas(orgatmp, conn);`
4. Test the F%%%% out of it.

I have just noticed the outer `While` Loop.  Is it there just to confuse you ?  How many times will it execute ? ...

---

I did wonder about the datareader -
 try this - I see that your datareader needs to close before you recurse, so close it.

in pseudocode -

```
dim locallist = new list();
while dr.read
{
  LocalList.Add dr.thing;
}
dr.close;

foreach(thing in locallist)
{
   if Not ValueInColl(thing) Then
     CallYourFunctionTRecursively()
   end if;
}
```

Are you with me ?

---

If you are trying to put together all the members of a family then it depends which database system you are using how it is done, but look up 'Heirarchical queries' in your documentation.

Comment: Ahh thats a great Idea. So I basically use one connection instead of opening one after another and closing them afterwards. I'll check that out. Thanks dude. :)

Comment: I think so, but it depends a little bit on what the StoredProc is doing - if there are commits and rollbacks in there it could all start to get very messy.

Comment: Uhm .. Actually I'm not 100% sure why I inserted another while, but I probably need it..  Now that I look at it though it seems pretty much useless. I'll take a look at it later on. The Stored procedure is btw just a simple select statement.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't seem to work, because of the datareader. I can use the same connection over and over again, but that doesn't count for the datareader. I can't close it though, because the dr is still in the while-loop. So ... yea. On the other hand I changed the outer while to a simple if clause. This might even solve my problem, but we'll see .. If anybody finds another possible solution tell me. I'll update the original post.

Comment: @user854699 - The outer `while` is a bit of a red herring, except that it does suggest the code is a bit bonkers.  Is there any way you can replace the Stored procedure call with a simple `SELECT DISTINCT` query to compile the list you want ?  Without deeper informaiton on your data structures and the SP it is difficult to go further with this.

Comment: What the hell is recurse? I can't at least not as far as I can tell use a query in exchange for the recursive-while. See I have an Id which either 0 or x fathers. This is basically what the whole function does. 1. round: select fatherid where id = @id ->getOrgas(fatherid), 2. round .... I couldn't think of a way to do this with sql.

Comment: Oh and I might've found the error (which was the data itself). Apparently there are some cases where childrenid = fatherid which results in an endless-while-loop which would end up endlessly creating new connections. We'll see

Comment: Ok, still have the same problem and I can't close the datareader, because it might still find values. The datareader contains all fatherids connected to the daughterid. Man .. this is annoying. Is there a way to check how many connections are open?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27922/discussion-between-hugh-jones-and-user854699)